# TypeError: array.concat is not a functionRedux Form:FieldArray

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to develop a FieldArray within my Redux-Form, but run into the following error when I press the button 'Add Policy':

> Uncaught TypeError: array.concat is not a function

My FieldArray calls a component:

```
<FieldArray name="policies" component={this.renderPolicies} />
```

The renderPolicies() helper function looks as follows:

```
renderPolicies = ({ fields, meta }) => {
return (
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => fields.push({})}>
        Add Policy
      </button>
      {this.renderError(meta)}
    </li>
    {fields.map((policy, index) => (
      <li key={index}>
        <button
          type="button"
          title="Remove Policy"
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
        />
        <h4>Policy #{index + 1}</h4>
        <Field
          name={`${policy}.id`}
          type="text"
          component={renderInput}
          label="Id"
        />
      </li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the same issue, make sure your arrayfield is not initialized to null, this is what happened to me

Comment: This seemed to fix the issue.  Not 100% sure the mechanics behind it, but thank you SO much!.

Answer (score 0):

What does your validation function look like? Take a look here: https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/fieldarrays/.